# Automated code generation of wxs and building installations

Tags: wix, wix3.7

I need your help, your opinions... What I want to do is build my installation on server... The problem is that this build will be very frequent, because after each commit, the build server make a new build...

What I am looking for is wxs file generation, because it's normal that developers create and delete files..., so I need to keep this wxs file up to date... and I can't do it manually...

Problem is that even Rob [wrote](http://www.mail-archive.com/wix-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg08779.html) that wix don't do that... I had thought that I can use heat to generate this... but some questions pop up...

1. I can't just build an install msi because if some components change(remove add new).. then there will be conflict...
2. I can't build it as small update or minor upgrade because it dont support component remove(http://www.joyofsetup.com/2008/12/30/paying-for-upgrades/ )... and also you can't just run msi by double click...
3. If I will building it like major upgrade, should I generate product GUID on each build?

Well if I choose a way of major upgrade I can generate new guids of components on each build and that way safely use heat.exe tool, if I will make a clean install...

Maybe other option is (I read a discussion when Rob and others told something about build own DB of guid for files...) just make an minor upgrade and use a bootstrapper so I can run it by double click... and also should use a DB of guids-files, so that way I don't need to make clean install...

Can you help me with this? How are you doing something like this?

Comment: You could argue that updating the installer is a task every developer should be able to perform. So if a developer introduces a new file - the developer task includes updating the installer.

Comment: But I can`t ask every developer to learn wix, and teach them how to edit that file...

Comment: I agree with @MortenFrederiksen. WiX is just xml. Plus, with all the 4.0 simplifications that slipped into 3.7 (default component and file id), the devs just need to add/remove components and files where the only attribute is File/@Source.